# Wordpress SELECT from data base

Tags: php, database, wordpress

In `Wordpress` data base I have table banners, I try to write `SELECT` to get data:

`'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->banners'` also try `'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_banners'` but no one query get me ressults, what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$wpdb->banners` needs to be a) defined somewhere (I'm not sure how this is handled in Wordpress, so you may or may not be using the right variable) and b) interpreted by PHP.

In what you've pasted here, you seem to be using single quotes, which will stop PHP interpreting the variable - it will assume you mean a literal `$`, which will lead to invalid SQL. You need to either use double quotes - `"SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->banners}"` - or string concatenation - `'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->banners`